Is the first-order theory of the class of well-ordered sets the same as the first-order theory of the class of ordinals?
Consider the class $K$ of well-ordered sets $(W,\leq)$. Although that class is not first-order axiomatizable, it has an associated first-order theory $Th(K)$. Now consider the class of ordinals $On$, where each ordinal $\alpha \in On$ is equipped with the $\leq$ relation. Is the first-order theory of $On$ the same as the first-order theory of $K$? I apologize if this question is too elementary.

I'm confused about what $Th(K)$ is. Does the language have a symbol $\le$ that compares well-ordered sets with each other? If so, how is it defined/interpreted? And does the language include equality?

Yes, since every ordinal is a well-ordered set, and every well-ordered set is isomorphic to an ordinal. So the classes are the same (up to isomorphism).

Naively, couldn't the theories differ because there's only one ordinal per isomorphism class? Are we considering a language with equality?

@Karl we're not somehow thinking of the whole class as a single first-order structure. When $K$ is a class of $L$-structures, $\mathrm{Th}(K)$ is the set of all $L$-sentences true of all structures in $K$. In this case, $L={\leq}$ is the language of order in first-order logic with equality.
